# Magento 2 - use LESS variables in custom LESS file

Tags: magento2, css, less

I added bootstrap 4 to my site, but it overwrites many magento 2 core css.

So I added a new file **THEME\web\css\bootstrap.less** where I try to fix these problems, and added it to my **THEME\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml**.

## THEME\web\css\bootstrap.less:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
    font-size: @font-size__base;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}

.nav { display: block; }
```

But if I compile then I get **NameError: variable @font-size__base is undefined in pub/static/frontend/company/fresh/de_DE/css/bootstrap.less on line 3, column 16:**, because I am using the variable `@font-size__base` which is defined in *lib\web\css\source\lib\variables\_typography.less*

How can I use magento less core variables in my custom css file?

My theme inherits from magento luma.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new bootstrap.less file, please create _bootstrap.less file in  **<your_theme>/web/css/source/extends** directory.

Then:

1. Create the **_extend.less** file in **<your_theme>/web/css/source/**
2. Import your _bootstrap.less in this file:

   @import 'extends/_bootstrap.less';
3. Make sure that your theme inherits from **Magento/luma** or **Magento/blank** theme - this is necessary if you want to use Magento variables
4. Recompile your styles

I hope this helps you.
Thanks,
Marcin

Comment: Thank you, but this will compile my bootstrap.less into the files *styles-l.css* and *styles-m.css* which both get loaded **before** the bootstrap 4 css file. This means that my overwrites will get overwritten again by bootstrap 4 ... So I need a separate css file which gets loaded after the bootstrap 4 css file.